# Matching and Managing Optional Groups in Regex Python

Tags: python-2.7, regex-group

I am trying to match the following string
(Studio) - Film (Year) - Segment Number

The string has to have the following order Studio, followed by Film then optional Year and finally optional (Segment + Number)

Studio and Film must be present
Year can be optional
Segment type (case insensitive), if present must be followed by a number ranging from 1 through 8
The types of segments incle

The regex should match the following strings
(studio) - film (1994) - CD 3
(studio) - film (1994)
(studio) - film - CD 3

I have tried the following Regex

`\((?P<STUDIO>.+)\) - (?P<TITLE>.+) \((?P<YEAR>\d{4})\)?( - (?P<SEGMENT>(?i)(cd|disc|disk|dvd|part|pt|scene) \b[1-8]\b))?`

Which gives the following for the string **(studio) - film (1994) - cd 3**

Named groups

- STUDIO    studio
- TITLE     film
- SEGMENT   cd 3
- YEAR      1994

and for **(studio) - film (1994)**

Named groups

- STUDIO    studio
- TITLE     film
- SEGMENT   None
- YEAR      1994

So it works as the segment is optional.

However, when I make the year optional by using the following regex:

`\((?P<STUDIO>.+)\) - (?P<TITLE>.+)?( \((?P<YEAR>\d{4})\))??( - (?P<SEGMENT>(?i)(cd|disc|disk|dvd|part|pt|scene) \b[1-8]\b))?`

I end up with this result:

Named groups

- STUDIO    studio
- TITLE     film (1994)
- SEGMENT   None
- YEAR      None

And if I remove the year all together so the string is like **(studio) - film - cd 3**, I get the following:

Named groups

- STUDIO    studio
- TITLE     film - cd 3
- SEGMENT   None
- YEAR      None

What I need is:

Named groups

- STUDIO    studio
- TITLE     film
- SEGMENT   cd 3 or None
- YEAR      1994 or None

Comment: Are you really using Python 2.7?

Comment: yes, I am using python 2.7 as indicated

Answer (score 1):

You might write the pattern as

```
(?i)^\((?P<STUDIO>[^()]*)\) - (?P<TITLE>.+?)?(?: \((?P<YEAR>\d{4})\))?(?: - (?P<SEGMENT>cd|disc|disk|dvd|part|pt|scene) [1-8])?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?P<STUDIO>[^()]*)` Group *STUDIO* Match chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\) -`  Match `) -`
- `(?P<TITLE>.+?)?` Group *TITLE* Match 1+ chars as least as possible
- `(?:`  Non capture group and match

  - `\((?P<YEAR>\d{4})\)` Match `(` then 4 digits in group *YEAR* and `)`
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-` Match literally
  - `(?P<SEGMENT>cd|disc|disk|dvd|part|pt|scene)` Group *SEGMENT* Match any of the alternatives
  - `[1-8]` Match a space and a digit 1-8
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8g3Eca/1)

Comment: Many thanks for this - as I only wanted the SEGMENT part as case insensitive, I changed it to this '''^\((?P<STUDIO>[^()]*)\) - (?P<TITLE>.+?)?(?: \((?P<YEAR>\d{4})\))?(?: - (?i)(?P<SEGMENT>(cd|disc|disk|dvd|part|pt|scene) [1-8]))?$'''